# How do you use the global hotkeys with VLC?

Tags: shortcut-keys, vlc

I have vlc installed and am trying to use it for transcription. It's not working because I can't run the hotkeys. I've removed all references to the keys in gnome keyboard shortcuts and, nothing... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.